# clickable results in php

Tags: php, mysql, clickable

Trying to display results that are clickable.

```html
<form method="post" action="AF9.php">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value=" search ">
            <input type="text" name="search" />
</form>
```

and here is partially the AF9.php file:

```php
<?php

        $connection = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME, MYSQLUSER, MYSQLPASS, MYSQLDB);
        if ($connection->connect_error) {
         die('Connect Error: ' . $connection->connect_error);
        }
        else {

        $search=$_POST["search"];

        $query="SELECT *,  FROM comments AS c JOIN namestable2 AS w ON c.w1 = w.w1
        WHERE name like '%$search%' 
        ORDER BY name DESC";                         
        $connection->query("SET NAMES utf8");               
        $result_obj = '';
        $result_obj = $connection->query($query);             

        while($result = $result_obj->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {   
        $items[] = $result;
        }                               

        foreach ($items as $item) {
        echo('<a href="AF9.php?search='.$item['word'].'">'.$item['word'].'</a>');

}?>
```

however when I click on the result, it says "Undefined index: search". Please help

Comment: Have you tried to print out out every `POST` variable to see what is actually passed in?

Comment: thanks everybody, your answers solved my problem.

Comment: Putting `$_POST` data directly in the query without escaping? [What could possibly go wrong!?](http://bobby-tables.com/). Remember, `mysqli` has a [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method. **Use it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hardcoded links that end with "?key=value" like "?search=xyz" will pass via the GET stream, not the POST.  Try changing this:

```
$search=$_POST["search"];
```

to this:

```
$search=$_GET["search"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you meant to do `$search=$_POST["search"];`?

If you're sending it in the URL, you'll need to do `$search=$_GET["search"];` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your link is a $_GET not $_POST change

```
$search=$_POST["search"];
```

to

```
$search = $_GET['search'];
```

Comment: no he's talking about a clickable link. This line I'm assuming `echo('<a href="AF9.php?search='.$item['word'].'">'.$item['word'].'</a>');` It's not a form submission.